# How to add .sty file

Tags: installing, miktex2.9

I am using texmaker with a latex file, but after compile .sty not found error comes.

I am using mikTex console, can you recommend some solution or some other installer other than miktex?

Thanks.

Comment: normally miktex works fine. What error do you get exactly? Show a small, complete example of your code and the log-file.

Comment: miktex or texlive are the two main distributions of tex, I use texlive myself but millions use miktex without problems. If you gave some information about what you did and what error you got, someone could help.

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of your last question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558128/sty-file-not-found-in-texmaker You still have not said in that question or this one which .sty file is missing.